# How do I rename a file in Python with a random file name?

Tags: python, file, random, rename

I am trying to code a program/horror game which requires me to download a file, place it on the Desktop, and rename it to a random set of lowercase letters.

This is the code I have to generate and define the random symbols:

```
# Importing random to generate
# random string sequence
import random
    
# Importing string
import string
    
def rand_pass(size):
        
    # Takes random choices from
    # ascii_letters and digits
    generate = ''.join([random.choice(
                        string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits)
                        for n in range(size)])
                            
    return generate
    
# Driver Code
glitchtext = rand_pass(10)
print(glitchtext)
```

It is currently working.

And these are the lines of code that rename the file. No need to show the rest of the code because it is all working, I just need to know how to rename it.

Here is the code:

```
#Defines what to name the file
oldname = (os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop", "ekZLFLzm.jpg"))
newname = (os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop", "random_text_here.jpg"))

#Renames the file
os.rename(oldname, newname)
```

So basically I'm just trying to use the variable "glitchtext" to name the file. If anyone knows how please respond. Thank you!

Comment: I don't realy understand where the problem is

Comment: Just a side note: Focus your question on the problematic. Here we don't have to know how the name is randomly generated. The question would rather be "How to include variable in a string?"

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was wrong,

I needed to add:

```
(glitchtext) + ".jpg"))
```

to my code to make this:

```
newname = (os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop", (glitchtext) + ".jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in order to fomat a string with variables is to use a [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

In your case the solution would be :

```py
newname = (os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop", f"{glitchtext}.jpg"))
```